# How to use loginContext in RMI server?

Tags: java, authentication, jaas

I have an RMI application where i need to use the loginContext object. I cant figure out how to implement this technology in my application any idea ??

```
        auth = new LoginContext(username);
        auth.login();
```

I've tried using the code above but is this enough to create a security policy in my application ?

Comment: This is a JAAS question, not an RMI question. RMI really has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Can't we use LoginContext in java RMI ??

Comment: Illogical. *Of course* you can use `LoginContext` with RMI, but your difficulty is with *how to use `LoginContext,`* not how to use it with RMI.

Comment: Can you show me how to implement the LoginContext in my RMI app ? maybe A link on how to implement it in my app